# plotting phase portrait for a system

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to plot phase portrait for below system
\begin{cases}
d\phi/d\zeta=Z   \\
dZ/d\zeta=a\phi+b\phi^2+c\phi^3
\end{cases}
a=-0.13
b=-0.07
c=-2.83
Can any body help me?
Thanks

Comment: You can't really, if $a, b$ and $c$ are unknown.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the MATHEMATICA script

`tmax = 10;
gr1 = StreamPlot[{-0.13 phi - 0.07 phi^2 - 2.83 phi^3, z}, {z, -1, 1}, {phi, -1, 1}];
sol = NDSolve[
 {phi'[t] == z[t], 
    z'[t] == -0.13 phi[t] - 0.07 phi[t]^2 - 2.83 phi[t]^3, 
     z[0] == 0.6, phi[0] == 0.6}, {z, phi}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{z[t], phi[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr1, gr2]`

we get the stream flow in blue and a typical orbit in red.

[image]